# Always display current year until next 2 years

Tags: php, datepicker

i think this problem quite simple, but i still stuck here. I want to display current year + next 2 years. For example if now is 2013, it will display 2013, 2014, 2015 and if this year is 2014, it will display 2014, 2015, 2016.

Here my coding

```
$myCalendar->setYearInterval(date('Y'), 2015);

    function setYearInterval($start, $end){
    $this->year_start_input = $start;
    $this->year_end_input = $end;

    if(!$start) $start = $this->year_start;
    if(!$end) $end = $this->year_end;

    if($start < $end){
        $this->year_start = $start;
        $this->year_end = $end;
    }else{
        $this->year_start = $end;
        $this->year_end = $start;
    }
```

I did changed 2015 to +2 / -2, but it's show 2011,2012,2013 (current year + 2 years back). Please help. Thanks.

Comment: can we see what is the code inside `setYearInterval` function.?

Comment: There is no such PHP core function like `setYearInterval()`. Where does it come from? Which calendar class are you using here?

Comment: He most likely uses http://www.triconsole.com/php/calendar_datepicker.php

Answer (score 2):

Why not use:

```
$myCalendar->setYearInverval(date('Y'), date('Y')+2);
```

Assuming you are using the Calendar Date Picker by triconsole. ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you indeed use http://www.triconsole.com/php/calendar_datepicker.php like mentioned above, this should do it.

```
$myCalendar->dateAllow(from, to, false)
```

If you leave from or to empty, all dates before or after can be chosen. False here means the other dates are disabled. You can put dates here, so for example you can disable all dates before today. You could also use the following if you want complete year ranges (instead of date ranges)

```
$myCalendar->setYearInverval(date('Y'), date('Y')+2);
```